# Make a div fly into another div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a webshop and struggling a bit with jQuery.

When someone clicks the button to add a product, I want that product to fly over to the shopping cart (animated) but I really don't know how...

Here's the html:

```
<div id="shopping-cart">

<div class="product">Product</div>
<div class="product">Product</div>
<div class="product">Product</div>
<div class="product">Product</div>
```

So the functionality of jQuery would be someting like:

```
$('.product').click(function() {
   $(this).flyTo('#shopping-cart');
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: Insert the click function in a `$(document).ready(function {});`

Comment: I know it should be.. but that's not the point of the question.. I was asking how i can make a div visualy fly to another one..

Comment: So if you add the product to your shopping cart the product get's removed from the list aswell? (is your intention this)

Comment: Editting my comment: Have you tried this pen? http://codepen.io/ElmahdiMahmoud/pen/tEeDn

Comment: It would actually be rather simple.

Comment: Nope, the products won't be removes from the list.. I do an ajax call to put all the info in a session ;) but this question is just for the visual part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a jQuery script to "fly" it to a place on screen.

See an example [here](http://codepen.io/ElmahdiMahmoud/pen/tEeDn).

Comment: There you go, I was going to reccomend you to look at
http://api.jquery.com/offset/
And animate an absolutely positioned div to the offset of the basket